# Swift : Randomize UIButton Position within View

Tags: swift, uiview, position, location

I have a UIView that i want to appear in a random location within the width and height of the device. I also want the Y location to not be below 20pts. Here is what I've done, but the UIView sometimes appears off the screen or partially off the screen:

```
superDab = SuperDabButton(frame:CGRectMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((self.view?.frame.size.width)! - (superDabImage!.size.width)))),
            (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((self.view?.frame.size.height)! - (superDabImage!.size.height))))),
            (superDabImage!.size.width),
            (superDabImage!.size.height)),
            time: 5.0)
        self.view?.addSubview(superDab!)
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: What determines the width and height of the button? Is it being resized after the init(frame:)?

Comment: The width and the height of the button is determined by the size of a UIImage. So in this case, it was superDabImage. Did that answer your question? @DavidWong

Comment: Is that image set to clip to bounds?

Comment: Yes, if it makes it easier, we can give that image height and width a value of 50pts. All it does is spit back a CGFloat value of the size of the image i have in my assets. @DavidWong

Comment: Hang on, is it going off screen on the top and left borders? I can see that arc4random_uniform(viewSize) might produce 0 and minusing the height and width will put that off screen.

Comment: YES! WOW I didn't even notice that. But i still need to consider that the maximum x value can't be more than ((self.view.bounds.width) + (superDabImage!.size.width)) . How could i write all that i said, in code? Im kinda new to this haha. @DavidWong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work by doing this and can be applied to anything with the same concept:

```
var xPos = CGFloat()
var yPos = CGFloat()

//Finds random CGFloat within the width and height
xPos = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((self.view?.frame.size.width)!))))
yPos = (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((self.view?.frame.size.height)!))))

//If statements saying that if the x pos is larger than the width - the size of the button, 
then do modulus on it using the equation below 
if (xPos > ((self.view?.bounds.width)! - (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20)){
    xPos = xPos % ((self.view?.bounds.width)! - (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20)}
if (yPos > ((self.view?.bounds.height)! - (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20)){
    yPos = yPos % ((self.view?.bounds.height)! - (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20)}

//Note: I use the "- (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20" for the ypos only because 
my button is a circle, so most likely others would use the height instead of width
```